# c# WindowsMediaPlayer End of Audio

Tags: c#, duration, windows-media-player

I am playing an Audio use Windows Media Player in c# WinForms. I want to display a message at the end of the audio play back.

I have a separate Audio class for playing audio and in the play method I have written:

```
Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();


public static void play()
{
   Player.controls.play();
   Player.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange);
}

private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
        isComplete=true;
}

public static boolean hasCompleted()
{ 
      return isComplete;
}
```

here isComplete is a boolean variable initialized to false

In my form, the code for my play button is:

```
//Play my audio
while(!hasCompleted());

//display message
```

The problem is that when i click the play button, my application goes into an infinite loop.

However when i do this:

```
 while(!hasCompleted())
    MessageBox.Show("Playing");

 //display message
```

It works fine.
Why is this happening?
I dont want to display a message while it's playing.
I tried using:

```
    Player.currentMedia.duration
```

and duration string property for a timer or Thread.sleep application but the value returned by both is always 0.

I also tried giving a delay of 1-2 seconds before calling the duration property but this doesn't work as some of my audio tracks are just 2 seconds long.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best way to do so since you are in a busy waiting situation which waste a lot of CPU cycles and may not work as you wish. I would recommend you to use "Event". Here you can find a very basic example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx